# How do I add an new object to an existing group?

Tags: selection-tools

Hi I am wondering if there's a way to add new object to an existing group.
I tried ctrl + shift + G but it only adds object to the collection instead of the "grp" unit. I can also ungroup and regroup again with the new obejct included, but I just wanna make sure if there's a faster way too add new things in the group.

Comment: A 'Group' in Blender **is** a Collection! If you want to add a new object to a collection, select the object in Object mode, hit 'M' and then either select the collection you want it in, or New if you want a new collection. You can drag and drop it from one Collection to another in the outliner too.

Comment: Groups don't exist anymore in the latest versions, they have been replaced by collections

Comment: Without knowing how your scene is set up or what objects and collections exist there, I don't even understand what the "grp unit" is or which one is "the" collection the object is added to.